# Punctuation following "My question is..."

Tags: punctuation, commas, syntactic-analysis, indirect-question

Forgive me if this has been asked before (if it has been, I couldn't find it)

What punctuation, if any, should I use after "My question is..."?

For example,

> My question is why is ice so slippery?
>
> My question is, why is ice so slippery?
>
> My question is: why is ice so slippery?

Which is the correct way to do it? (If it matters, MLA style please)

Comment: `Why is ice so slippery?` is not formal English, it should be `Why ice is so slippery?`

Comment: @Khaled A Khunaifer The whole debate addressing 'What are the correct forms for quote and report, and possibly hybrid, structures?' is ongoing, and there is as yet no consensus.

Comment: @KhaledAKhunaifer You need inversion in questions. *My question is, “Why is ice so slippery?”*  This is different from saying *The question at hand is why ice is so slippery.*

Answer (score 3):

Some style guides recommend refraining from using colons after verbs, so if there is going to a pedant reading your text, it might be better to say “My question is *[ the following | thus | this ]*: why is ice so slippery?”.  That actually sounds better to me anyways, but there's nothing wrong with what you had.

No comma doesn't work because of the inverted subject-verb order.

The comma one is *technically* okay, but I personally rather dislike it.  *The Handbook of Good English* calls it a sort of “soft colon” (and grants a capital letter to the question if you want further emphasis on the question), but no matter how many times I see it, it just looks *wrong* to my eyes since you don't write “My question is, not important” or “My question is, really a statement”.  But I digress.

That said, you have a few other options that work too depending on your taste:

- My question is<sub>( , )</sub> “Why is ice so slippery?”
- My question is why ice is so slippery.
- I question why ice is so slippery.

Comment: Can you please clarify? Are you saying that HGE licenses << My question is, why is ice so slippery? >> and << My question is, Why is ice so slippery? >>? And << My question is: why is ice so slippery? >> and << My question is: Why is ice so slippery? >>? (I've been trying to find someone who does!)

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Probably.  I admit I reference HGE via another answer on here (that I can't seem to find now) that quoted it using the comma as such (and mentioning capitals).  I would imagine if it allows a capital with a mere "soft colon" comma, that it would approve of the true colon + capital.  But do us readers a favor and just do an indrect question or use quotation marks ;-)

Comment: Found it; copied it. Thanks. Evil grin. But agree that your recommendations are sound.